# found 1 low severity vulnerability

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a `react` project and I found the below error:

```
58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

and this is the cmd:

```
D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects>npx create-react-app my_app_test --use-npm
npx: installed 98 in 50.461s

Creating a new React app in D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\React_Redux_Course\React Projects\my_app_test\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react@16.13.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1624 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1628 packages in 1030.934s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

any one knows what is the problem and how can I solve this?

## Edited:

it freezes on this line, till I found this message

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

I tried `npm audit fix` and shows the below result:

```
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-16T20_54_24_759Z-debug.log
```

when I tried to run this command for fist time I found the below warning:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                  npm update check failed                  │
│            Try running with sudo or get access            │
│           to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\DELL\.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I run this command again the warning gone

Comment: "run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details"

Comment: This is not an error too, it's just a notice. You can ignore it and still run the app in most situations.

Comment: @JonathanRosa it freezes on this warning every time

Comment: @BrianThompson already tried this but it didn't solved yet

Comment: Ok then the complete question should include that you have already tried that, and what it told you. It should also include what *freezes* means, since it looks like it completed successfully to me.

Comment: @BrianThompson thanks for your support :) I have already edited the question could you please check :D

Comment: @BrianThompson I think i have to install `package.json` or something?

Comment: did it really take 17mins to install, the freezing might be your computer

Comment: The vulnerability is nothing you can do anything about. CRA manages the dependencies for you, so I believe you would have to eject to change anything (its been a while since I've used CRA though). However, I wouldn't worry about it, it says its low. I would focus on what *freezing* means

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have left the pc installing it for one hour and still freeze may be I have to restart the computer??... it was strange